# Issue rendering Item list in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a list of items on screen but getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

What I'm missing/doing wrong here in my code?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import RecipeListItem from  './RecipeListItem';

const RecipeList = ({recipes}) => {

    const Items = recipes.map((recipe) => {
      return <RecipeListItem key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe} />
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {Items}
        </div>
    )
}

export default RecipeList
```

Comment: Where is `recipes` defined? How is the component receiving that data? What happens if you `console.log(recipes)`?

Comment: I'm guessing that the parent component passes `recipes` in as a prop from its state - have you defined `recipes` in the parent's state?

Comment: Yes. I have defined recipes in a Constructor in App.js, then I have  <RecipeList /> but I see I didn't pass the state to that component. I tried passing it like <RecipeList recipes={this.state}/> but it doesn't work.

Comment: made it work adding recipes.recipes to my map function: `const Items = re.recipes.map((recipe) => {
  return <RecipeListItem key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe} />
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend not passing the entire parent state to the child - set it up like this:

In `App.js`, pass the prop like so:

```
<RecipeList recipes={this.state.recipes} />
```

Then just reference `props` in the child -

```
const RecipeList = (props) => {

    const Items = props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
      return <RecipeListItem key={recipe.id} recipe={recipe} />
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {Items}
        </div>
    )
}

export default RecipeList
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my code I'm referencing not as props but as {recipes}: `const RecipeList = ({recipes}) => {` whats is the best practice?

Comment: no. Actualy when I use destructuring like {recipes} I end up with this working well: `const Items = recipes.map((recipe) => {`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your earlier comment. I'd just reiterate the bit about not passing the entire parent state to the child.

Comment: My personal preference is to not use destructuring very much, since it's not as explicit.